# How to split a string with a separator that is not preceded by a character?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string `str = "Jake!!!Jackson!!!Tyson\\!!!!!!Pete"`

I want to split the string by `!!!` but ignore it if the char before `!!!` is `"\\"`.

I came up `str.split("(?<!\\\\)!!!");`

But the output is `Jake,Jackson,Tyson\!,!!Pete` and the expected output is `Jake,Jackson,Tyson\!!!,Pete`

Can this be accomplished by regex?

Comment: The usual problem in these cases is: can your string contain escape sequences? I.e., do you want to split in case you have `Tyson\\!Pete` (in Java, defined as `"Tyson\\\\!Pete"`)?

Comment: No, only split !!!.

Comment: Then you probably can use the solution below. A single `(?<!\\)` (in Java, `"(?<!\\\\)"`) lookbehind solution will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following could work:

```
(?<!\\)!!!(?=(?:!!!)*(?!!))
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZwTxBa/1)

- `(?<!\\)` - Assert position not preceded by a literal backslash.
- `!!!` - Literally three exclamation marks.
- `(?=` - Open positive lookahead:

  - `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

    - `!!!` - Literally three exclamation marks.
    - `)*` - Close non-capture group and match 0+ times.
  - `(?!!)` - Negative lookahead for exclamation mark.
- `)` - Close positive lookahead.

This would split a string like `Jake!!!Jackson!!!Tyson\!!!!!!!Pete` including a NULL too (assuming that is what you are after). As a Java-string: `"(?<!\\\\)!!!(?=(?:!!!)*(?!!))"`

Comment: @Amessihel, can you tell me what typo?

Comment: Actually I see the error with an old version of Firefox but not more recent version of Chrome. ECMAScript issue? Anyway what I said isn't relevant.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! "(?<!\\\\)!!!(?=(?:!!!)*(?!!))" works fine for exclamation mark, but if I replace ! with ~ "(?<!\\\\)~~~(?=(?:~~~)*(?~~))" it gives inline modifier error @ ((?~~). Do you know why?

Comment: @Michael, don't replace the 1st exclamation mark in the negative lookahead.